# How to implement "High Availability" for Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Does Azure Synapse Analytics support Geo-Redundancy like Storage Account & Key vault? If not, why do I implement High availability for Azure Synapse Analytics? I have the following components as a part of the Azure Synapse Analytics Solution

- SQL Dedicated Pool
- SQL Serverless Pool
- Spark Pool
- Storage Account(ADLS)
- Azure DevOps Git Repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, designing and documenting a Disaster Recovery plan is a project unto itself. I’ve been working on one for a client of mine using Synapse for several months part-time.

The first task is to define your Recovery Time Objective (RTO, meaning how long before your solution is back up in the event of a disaster) and your Recovery Point Objective (RPO, meaning how many minutes or hours of data you can afford to lose… and with analytics solutions you can usually reload from the source to catch up). If your RTO and RPO are low for an analytics solution (like 2 hours) then you probably need to spin up parallel environments in another region and load data to both environments in parallel. If your RTO and RPO are typical for an analytics solution (24-48 hours) then you can probably survive with ensuring backups are geo-redundant and restoring in the event of an outage. I would recommend you preconfigured your Synapse workspace and other infrastructure before the outage unless you have a trust an infrastructure as code solution. If your RPO and RTO are long (like 7 days) it’s extremely unlikely an Azure service or region is going to be down for that long.

ADLS supports [RA-GRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy) redundancy so you could read all the files from the secondary endpoint in its [pair region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/cross-region-replication-azure#azure-cross-region-replication-pairings-for-all-geographies) and copy files to another ADLS in the secondary region. Unfortunately ADLS accounts don’t yet support user-initiated [failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal).

Dedicated SQL Pools support built-in [geo redundant backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-from-geo-backup) once a day but you can’t control when they are taken. If this isn’t acceptable then you need to proactively create a [user-defined restore point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-points) and proactively restore it cross region and pause the SQL pool.

Synapse Serverless SQL pools have no storage so ensure you have a backup of the schema (views, permissions, external data sources, external tables, etc) in source control or somewhere. The data will failover with ADLS.

For Spark Pools ensure you have your notebook artifacts in source control and you can always run them in a different Synapse workspace in another region when needed. Document your cluster configs.

Write out a disaster recovery playbook and do a DR drill periodically (once a quarter or once a year).

Here is another author’s description of the [DR plan for Synapse](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/some-notes-azure-synapse-disaster-recovery-andrei-zaichikov).

Comment: Great explanation. Does the Dedicated SQL Pools support High availability?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar yes Synapse supports high availability (to survive hardware outages and patching) in a single region. It doesn’t automatically provide high availability across regions. Here is the SLA: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/synapse-analytics/v1_1/